# Change line thickness for specific line in ggplot in R

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I would like to change the line thickness for `State = "A"` to 2, but `scale_size_manual` doesn't seem to work for `stat_smooth` type of line-plotting.

Could someone let me know how to change line thickness for this specific condition?

```
   aaa = data.frame(State=rep(c("A","B","C"),100),x= rnorm(300),y=rnorm(300))
   ggplot(aaa,aes(x=x, y=y,col=State))+ 
          geom_point() + 
          stat_smooth(method=glm,se=FALSE,aes(col=State)) +  
          scale_size_manual(values = c(2,1,1))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `size=State` in `stat_smooth`, i.e.:

```
ggplot(aaa,aes(x=x, y=y,col=State))+ 
       geom_point() + 
       stat_smooth(method=glm,se=FALSE,aes(col=State,size=State)) +  
       scale_size_manual(values = c(2,1,1))
```

[image]